# Something went wrong with the subscription alert in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, newsletter, alert

I have a clean **Magento 2.1.0** installation running on my server, and for some reason the newsletter subscription box keeps displaying the following error: "Something went wrong with the subscription." However, the address is successfully stored in the Database.

**Has anyone else had this error recently and how did you fix it?** I've tried googling it but not much luck as the Magento GitHub states this is a bug that has been fixed in earlier releases.

Thanks.!

Answer (score 3):

It's unable to send the email confirmation for whatever reason. You need to configure your server to allow php to send emails.